# How can a grunt plugin wrap another plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I was wondering how a Grunt plugin could wrap around another.

For example, a plugin could set some parameter and pass them while running the other Grunt task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How can I share parameters across multiple tasks?](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#how-can-i-share-parameters-across-multiple-tasks) in the docs.

Comment: Could one plugin inject configuration into another?

Comment: Yes, you can have one task run another. See the section `Dynamic alias tasks` where one tasks run another one with some parameter.